# Unable to locate package python-certbot-apache on Ubuntu 14.04 AWS

Tags: php, apache, ssl-certificate

I have tried installing certbot SSL certificate on apache. Following command I performed.

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt-get install python-certbot-apache

after running 3rd command I get below error.
**"Unable to locate package python-certbot-apache"**

if anyone can help me sort this out, would be great.

Comment: check this. https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntuother-apache

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same problem, although if you remove `sudo` at the beginning so it reads

```sh
apt-get install python-certbot-apache
```

It gives you a hint to the more up to date version.
So, it should do it if you use

```sh
sudo apt install python3-certbot-apache
```

```
sudo apt install -y certbot python3-certbot-apache
```

Comment: is this will work on AWS ip and my domain host is goDaddy? @Laravel

Comment: Yes, it'll work make sure to select the right option like apache on ubuntu.

Answer (score 68):

On most recent Ubuntu releases, the Certbot and its Apache plugin can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install -y certbot python3-certbot-apache
```

(note the **"python3"**, whereas most resources only mention "python")

Comment: Succesfully used also with Debian

Answer (score 15):

Certbot doesn't support the apt-get installation on Ubuntu 14 anymore. But you still can install. To do it, log in to the server via SSH and run:

```sh
wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
sudo mv certbot-auto /usr/local/bin/certbot
sudo chown root /usr/local/bin/certbot
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/certbot
```

Then use `certbot` as usual.

Source: https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/pip-apache

If you get an error like `CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated`, then:

```sh
# Remove the Certbot virtual environment
rm -r /opt/eff.org/certbot/

# Install a new version of Python 2.7
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.18/Python-2.7.18.tgz
tar xfz Python-2.7.18.tgz
cd Python-2.7.18/
sudo ./configure --prefix /usr/local/lib/python2.7.18
sudo make && sudo make install
cd ..
rm -r Python-2.7.18.tgz Python-2.7.18

# And run Certbot once with the new Python:
PATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7.18/bin:$PATH certbot renew
```

Then run `certbot` as usual.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer, thank you so much

Comment: when wget command, ERROR: cannot verify dl.eff.org's certificate. Issued certificate has expired.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, although if you remove `sudo` at the beginning so it reads

```sh
apt-get install python-certbot-apache
```

It gives you a hint to the more up to date version.
So, it should do it if you use

```sh
sudo apt install python3-certbot-apache
```